# creating space between bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm working off one of the examples previously posted on this forum. I want to put spaces between each of my plots because there is overlap of the index and I can barely read it. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
states = ["AK", "TX", "CA", "MT", "NM", "AZ", "NV", "CO", "OR", "WY", "MI",
          "MN", "UT", "ID", "KS", "NE", "SD", "WA", "ND", "OK", 
         "AK1", "1TX", "C1A", "1MT", "N1M", "A1Z", "N1V", "C1O", "O1R", "W1Y", "1MI",
          "MN1", "UT1", "ID1", "KS1", "NE1", "S1D", "WA1", "ND1", "O1K", ]
staff = np.array([20, 30, 40, 10, 15, 35, 18, 25, 22, 7, 12, 22, 3, 4, 5, 8,
                  14, 28, 24, 32, 20, 30, 40, 10, 15, 35, 18, 25, 22, 7, 12, 22, 3, 4, 5, 8,
                  14, 28, 24, 32])
sales = staff * (20 + 10 * np.random.random(staff.size))

# Sort by number of sales staff
idx = staff.argsort()
states, staff, sales = [np.take(x, idx) for x in [states, staff, sales]]

y = np.arange(sales.size)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0].barh(y, staff, align='center', color='gray', zorder=10)
axes[0].set(title='Number of sales staff')
axes[1].barh(y, sales, align='center', color='gray', zorder=10)
axes[1].set(title='Sales (x $1000)')

axes[0].invert_xaxis()
axes[0].set(yticks=y, yticklabels=states)
axes[0].yaxis.tick_right()

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.margins(0.03)
    ax.grid(True)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.19)
plt.show()
```

And output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJR3P.png)

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Add a figure size as `fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 7))` and see if you get anything better. Also, try increasing `wspace` to more than 0.19

Comment: that works really well, thank you!